# PHP Regex: extract last number in filename

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex with extract me a number which is always at the end of a file wrapped in ().

For example:

> Vacation (1).png **returns 1**
>
> Vacation (Me and Mom) (2).png **returns 2**
>
> Vacation (5) (3).png **returns 3**

Hope some regex pros are out there :)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: jeroen nothing :( Regex is still a mistey to me. 
@PeeHaa No, but this can be checked with file_exists()

Answer (score 4):

This should do it ([demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/P1sFZT)):

```
preg_match( '/^.*\((\d+)\)/s', $filename, $matches );
$number = $matches[1];
```

The greedy `^.*` causes the regexp to first match as many characters as possible, and then to backtrack until it can match `\((\d+)\)`, i.e. a number surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: i dont want the amount of matches. I want the number between ( and ).

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe: ...and that's exactly what my code gives you.  Take a look at the demo (and the docs for [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match)) if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 4):

Just write it, `$` is the end of the subject:

```
$pattern = '/\((\d+)\)\.png$/';
$number  = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches) ? $matches[1] : NULL;
```

This is a so called anchored pattern, it works very well because the regular expression engine knows where to start - here at the end.

The rest in this crazy pattern is just quoting all the characters that need quoting:

```
(, ) and . => \(, \) and \. in:

().png     => \(\)\.png
```

And then a group for matches is put in there to only contain one or more (`+`) digits `\d`:

```
\((\d+)\)\.png
  ^^^^^
```

Finally to have this working, add the `$` to mark the end:

```
\((\d+)\)\.png$
              ^
```

Ready to run.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

```
preg_match_all('/\((\d+)\)/', $filename, $m); 
$num=end(end($m));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/(.+)\((\d+)\)\.png/';
    $test1 = "Vacation LDJFDF(1).png";
    $test2 = "Vacation (Me and Mom) (2).png";
    $test3 = "Vacation (5)(3).png";

    preg_match($pattern, $test1, $matches);
    print $matches[2];
    print "\n";

    preg_match($pattern, $test2, $matches);
    print $matches[2];
    print "\n";

    preg_match($pattern, $test3, $matches);
    print $matches[2];
    print "\n";

?>
```

php test.php
1
2
3